# How can I solve angular 12 app creating problem

Tags: node.js, angular12

[image]

Angular CLI: 12.1.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                          Node: 14.17.3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Package Manager: npm 7.19.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                  OS: win32 x64

Answer (score 0):

Open the folder you create with `ng new` and open the `package.json` file. In **devDependencies** change the version of **"jasmine-core" to 3.7.1** and **"karma-jasmine-html-reporter" to 1.7.0** and save it. Then go back to Terminal and go to your project and run `npm install`. Now it works and you can run `ng serve`.

Comment: I need that angular CLI automated installed npm, but the problem is solved when I opened the project and installed npm manually,  the app is running.